# How to address a cover letter for a small company without a dedicated Hiring Manager?

Tags: cover-letter

I want to apply for a job in a small company. The company consists of
a CEO (who probably makes the ultimate hiring decisions),
a CTO (who might influence those decisions ),
a HR person (apparently nontechnical),
other employees (not involved in the hiring process).

There is no one with the title "Hiring Manager".

How do I address the cover letter correctly, and who do I "greet" in the salutation line?

What I considered, and why I didn't like those ideas:

- "To whom it may concern" - awkward, everyone involved in the hiring process is listed on the website.
- "Dear Hiring Manager" - awkward, there is no Hiring Manager, and again, all names are known
- "Dear Mr. HRName HRSurname!" - again, awkward, because the job opening explicitly asks to say a few words about some technical details of a project based on a specific technology, and I don't expect the HR-person to understand all those details.
- "Dear Mr. CEOName CEOSurname" - seems a bit... hubristic?

How do I start the cover letter properly? Thanks.

---

There are many related questions, but they all have slightly different emphasis:

- [How do I address a cover letter if I can't find out who is responsible for hiring?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/5773/how-do-i-address-a-cover-letter-if-i-cant-find-out-who-is-responsible-for-hirin) - the underlying assumption seems to be that *there is* someone who is responsible specifically for hiring, and the applicant simply cannot find out *who* it is. In this question, it is clear that there is no dedicated hiring manager, there is only a non-technical HR-person who does some filtering, and then there is the CEO, without any "Dear Hiring Managers" in between.
- [Should you address a specific person in your cover letter?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/87045/should-you-address-a-specific-person-in-your-cover-letter)
- [Should you address a specific person in your cover letter at all cost?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/27941/should-you-address-a-specific-person-in-your-cover-letter-at-all-cost)

None of the answers there solved my specific problem, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I was asking about a company in the U.S. ; For me, it was sufficient to know that addressing the CEO directly is not widely considered inappropriate, so I accepted the answer.

Comment: There normally isn't a dedicated hiring manager. The hiring manager is the person who is hiring someone to fill a role as needed on a team a department they oversee. So depending on the role advertised, this person could have a title like Engineering Manager, Head Of Whatever, CTO, CEO, etc.

Comment: So, one should simply use common sense, and address the letter to the person who makes the decision. That's much simpler than expected. The lack of illogicality is almost anticlimactic :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I address a cover letter if I can't find out who is responsible for hiring?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/5773/how-do-i-address-a-cover-letter-if-i-cant-find-out-who-is-responsible-for-hirin). I know this is included in your question. But it covers your situation. You don't know who to address it to. Most of the time you will not know who to address it to.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep I edited the question to emphasize the difference between my question and the first link in the list of similar questions, I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Your letter will be read by the gatekeeper, the hiring manager, the HR representative, the person who will be conducting the phone interview, the person conducting the technical test, the five people who will interview you , and your new manager if you are hired. None of them care about the salutation used.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep Is that true in 100% of cases? Dear Sir or Madam (if sex is known)  or to whom it may concerne - is the formally correct way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Address it to the CEO, it will get passed on to the person charged to deal with that set of applications for that post.

Comment: So, simply address it directly to the person who is responsible for the ultimate decision, and don't mention the HR (who probably does some preliminary filtering) at all? Alright, thanks for the proposal. I'll wait a little bit and see whether there are other ideas. Sorry, can't upvote yet. Thank you very much so far.